# Removing dot after section letter

Tags: sectioning, punctuation

Right now this I'm getting this for my first subsubsection:

> G.1.1.

I would like for this to be

> G1.1.

Does anybody know if it is possible to remove the first dot and put G and 1 together without a space between? Code below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\setcounter{section}{7}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}
\subsubsection{Hello World} % G.1.1 I want it to be G1.1

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I took the liberty to reduce your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/). Please always do that before posting a question here; a MWE is our standard format and requirement, which makes it easier for others to identify your problem and help you with it. It actually turned out that none of your -- admittedly nicely organized -- preamble was relevant to the problem. You did forget `\end{document}` though. And I'd recommend using braces `{}` for `\renewcommand`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to redefine `\thesubsection`, i.e.,

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}}
```

Comment: Almost there, but now i'm getting 71.1 instead on G1.1?

Comment: @NielsSønderbæk: Use `\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}}`.

Comment: I accidentally deleted my first \renewcommand, which is what caused the mistake. Thank you so much!